# Map a tuple of objects to an object in typescript types

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I have a type that looks like this:

```js
type Config = {
  endpoints: [
    {name: "abc", created: false},
    {name: "xyz", created: true},
  ]
}
```

I have a function that transforms this type into the following:

```js
type Instance = {
  abc: {name: "abc", created: false},
  xyz: {name: "xyz", created: false},
}
```

I wrote the following transformation type

```js
type IntersectOf<U extends any> = (U extends unknown ? (k: U) => void : never) extends ((k: infer I) => void) ? I : never;

type Transform<T extends Config, K extends (keyof T)[] = (keyof T)[]> = IntersectOf<{
  [key in keyof K]:
    K[key] extends keyof T['endpoints']
    // here it says "name" can't be used as index of `T["endpoints"][K[key]]`
    ? Record<T['endpoints'][K[key]]['name'], T['endpoints'][K[key]]>
    : never;
}[number]>;

type Instance = Transform<Config>;
```

I also tried adding a number type guard, and the error goes away but `Instance` becomes `unknown`. Here is the `Transform` type with number typeguard:

```js
type Trasnform<T extends Config, K extends (keyof T)[] = (keyof T)[]> = IntersectOf<{
  [key in keyof K]:
    K[key] extends keyof T['endpoints']
    ? K[key] extends number
    ? Record<T['endpoints'][K[key]]['name'], T['endpoints'][K[key]]>
    : never
    : never;
}[number]>;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My suggestion would be to write a [key-remapping mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#key-remapping-via-as) that acts on the [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of element types of the `endpoints` property, like this:

```
type Transform<T extends { name: string }> =
    { [U in T as U['name']]: U }
```

And then you pass in, not `Config`, but the [indexed access type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) `Config['endpoints'][number]` corresponding to the element types:

```
type Instance = Transform<Config['endpoints'][number]>;
```

That produces this:

```
/* type Instance = {
    abc: {
        name: "abc";
        created: false;
    };
    xyz: {
        name: "xyz";
        created: true;
    };
} */
```

which is what you were looking for.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=8#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gOwGYEsDmUC8UDeAoKQqCBAEzDhQWAGcAuKAbQKNZygQEMBbCBgIk4AjAMb8ANFBEAnCJ2ARSDJJwA2NaAF9xLVoXZdeAgB4gAXhKmz5ihsGkBXLTtYBdPJrx5QkKABVpTgQaJDhpbgAeP2JjBTIaXA4ePigaeyoMTQA+LF1ExgBVKCp-KE4EgsYAckMIKtdXBiLPLx9oAElg4CCRaGwAoJCwyPhkdGqSckpqGnrGBAduIQhpVyyAbi8AegAqKDaoTrSevtw84REGfD0iWoEL-k2bwhk5BSUoFXUIJ6JNX8IpjMVzyrDuUH4QMeoKIrxsH3sTgBUH+HigOy2QA)

Comment: Working on the union, nice!

Comment: thanks a lot, I came across Key Remapping too but I wasn't able to make it work for my use case, Its working fine now

Answer (score 1):

A proposal ([playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=13&ssc=1&pln=16&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gOwGYEsDmUC8UDeBYAKCmKggQBMw4UFgBnALigG1CT3coEBDAWwiYAibgCMAxoIA0UMQCcI3YBHJMk3ADZ1oAX0lsOxHFz4CoggB4gAXlJnzFypsFkBXHXqIkAuoW2FCoJBQAJIIdMDcCGLQ2PiexKJiTEY8-EKJtnIKSipQapru%20sSWVsnGaWYlmfY5qhpaULq%20-gQQ5lSywFCB0KHkKNF0APJIADwAKgB8WFAAouZi6i7kEKMA1hAgcEhQ49IbWzuRIMxekwDcLT0hYRFREAD6M0bMweTmUDQ3-YMjo-DIdDMQRkSjUWh0QRnKDcOiwRCoNDA0FUGj0KGvd5eYGpCBQrxMAGI5EUVEQjFvcxeRqEIA)):

```
export type IndicesOf<T> = Exclude<keyof T, keyof any[]>;

type Instance = { 
  [Idx in IndicesOf<Config["endpoints"]> 
    as Config["endpoints"][Idx]["name"]]: Config["endpoints"][Idx]
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot, I really liked the `IndicesOf` approach.